How to use the equivalent to "EnumRequirement", available in a routing attribute, on YAML routing configuration?
What is the equivalent of this route requirements configuration in YAML format?
#[Route('/foo/{bar}', requirements: ['bar' => new EnumRequirement(SomeEnum::class)])]

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-1-improved-routing-requirements-and-utf-8-parameters#using-php-backedenum-as-route-requirements
foo_bar_controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/Foo/Bar
        namespace: App\Controller\Foo\Bar
    prefix: /{!_foobar}
    requirements:
        # How to instantiate the EnumRequirements class here ?
        _foobar: new Symfony\Component\Routing\Requirement\EnumRequirements(Foo\Bar::class)


https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-improved-enum-support

@u_mulder Thanks but it does not help. I’m looking for using EnumRequirements and not passing an enum.
